# Help Identifying This Burdock-Type Plant

Tags: identification

I have this kind of wild burdock-type plant that I can't identify... No flowers are yet available. The leaves are big and distinctive, with red spots on the stem bases. A kind of vegetable paper wraps the main stem of the plant. 
It is now almost 2 feet high and still growing.
I live in Québec, Canada, Zone 4.

[image: entire plant]

[image: single mature leaf]

[image: vegetable paper-like wrap]

[image: Young Leaves]

[image: Red Spots On Stems]

Comment: For me it is a Brassicaceae (cabbage family). 4 petal flowers (usually yellow or white). Horseradish has similar leaves and habits (but I do no remember the sheets o stem). Probably you should wait few more weeks to see the flowers..

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Seems wise to me too to wait for the flowers... It's very big though!